# Azure App Service with java or container returns only 404 when App Insights enabled

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I wanted to deploy a built spring boot jar to Azure AppService, but the chosen mode with Linux did responded only 404 "Not found" (that looked like Tomcat error page) after deploy although I could see in logs the app had been deployed correctly.
During troubleshooting I changed the mode of AppService to the one with container image. But it did not help.
Then I found the 404 is caused by enabling the App Insights which causes adding a `-javaagent:/agent/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar` to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTS` env var.

The `codeless` variant is not available anywhere online so with  some struggle I downloaded the jar to my local machine, set Insights connection string env variable and reproduced the error. With the applicationinsights-agent downloaded from github [releases](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/releases) I got different error, but did not investigate further.

When enabled, App Insights worked as I could see it send traces etc. But the HTTP routing in the app is broken therefore the App Insights is useless.

I don's see how I could fix this, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I am currently facing the exact same issue, did you make any progress? I started encountering this problem after upgrading from springboot 2.7.7 to 3.0.2 (java 11 tomcat 9 to 17 tomcat 10)

Comment: Which version of the `applicationinsights-agent` do you use?
I had exactly the same problem as you have, and it disappeared right after I upgraded the application insights agent to `applicationinsights-agent-3.4.9.jar`.

Comment: That was part of the problem. I enabled the Insights using App Service magic button in Azure Portal and it deployed the `codeless` agent which I can't say what version is. I peekd inside the jar and found string `version=3.2.11` in file `ai.sdk-version.properties` but the MANIFEST.MF contains `Created-By: 15.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)`

Answer (score -1):

There can be multiple scenarios which is causing the issue:

In your case you are getting 404 error, because your jar file might not deploy properly in App Services which is causing this issue.
Check if the below steps help to resolve your issue:

1. Try restarting your App service.
2. You may be trying to manually push the jar file through FTP in App Service which basically causes the problem during deployment, because it basically a step of copying the jar file into Tomcat webapps directory.
   So, you can deploy your jar file using maven plugin.

Below are the commands to configure and deploy the jar file in App Service of your spring boot application.
Command to configure the App Service:

```
mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.5.0:config
```

Command to package and deploy the jar file to App Service:

```
mvn package azure-webapp:deploy
```

**I have tried in my environment and got expected results:**

*I have used the above-mentioned commands to configure and deploy the jar file to **App Service**.*

[image]

[image]

I have enabled Application Insights and my application is working fine as expected.

[image]

***I have also tried with Docker Container:***

[image]

Enabled Application Insights:

[image]

Enabled Port 8080 by adding WEBSITES_PORT :8080 as a setting in Web App> Configuration>Application settings.

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I do not want tio use it with mvn deploy, but deploy it using Azure Pipeline. I am able to reproduce the error with agent jar downloaded to my machine. So I think I distilled to issue to the core.

Comment: Refer to the solutions provided in the [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974) ticket which may help you to fix the issue.